# Replace NA value for multiple factor variables in DataFrame

Tags: r, for-loop, dplyr

we have the DataFrame `df` with more than 200 columns ,It has two types of Variables `numeric` and `factor` . Both variables having the NA values .

`Step 1:` first have divided the data sets into two parts numeric and the datasets having only factor variables .

```
df_num <- (df , is.numeric)

df_factor <- select_if(df , is.factor)
```

step 2:

```
df <- df %>%
      mutate_if(is.numeric , funs(replace(., is.na(.), 0)))
```

step 3:

```
df_factor <- df_factor %>%
          mutate_if(is.character , funs(replace(., is.na(.), 0)))
```

i tried to write `for loop` for df_factor dataframe to replace all `"NA"` values to `"Some-value"`

```
col <- colnames(df_factor)

for (i in col) {
    df_factor$[i] <- as.numeric(nlevels()) #I am stuck here
}
```

could someone help on this?

Answer (score 2):

We could convert it into character and then `replace` the value

```
library(dplyr)
df_factor %>%
    mutate_all(funs(replace(as.character(.), is.na(.), "some_value")))
```

If you want to convert it back to `factor`

```
df_factor %>%
    mutate_all(funs(factor(replace(as.character(.), is.na(.), "some_value"))))
```

Or if we want to use `df` directly instead of `df_factor`

```
df %>%
  mutate_if(is.factor, funs(factor(replace(as.character(.), is.na(.), "some_value"))))
```

---

Adding a reproducible example to test

```
df <- data.frame(col1 = c(NA, letters[1:5]), col2 = c(1:5, NA), 
                 col3 = c(NA, letters[14:17], NA))

df

# col1 col2 col3
#1 <NA>    1 <NA>
#2    a    2    n
#3    b    3    o
#4    c    4    p
#5    d    5    q
#6    e   NA <NA>

df %>%
  mutate_if(is.factor, funs(factor(replace(as.character(.), is.na(.), "some_value"))))


#        col1 col2       col3
#1 some_value    1 some_value
#2          a    2          n
#3          b    3          o
#4          c    4          p
#5          d    5          q
#6          e   NA some_value
```

Answer (score 0):

I am still not totally sure what your goal is. The Loop seems a bit off though.

```
for (i in 1:length(col)){
  df_factor[,i] <- as.numeric(nlevels()) #I am stuck here
}
```

Works if you plug in a x value for nlevels()
Example: `nlevels(df_factor[,i])`

**Edit:**

If your goal is to replace the NA's with the factorlevels, then

```
df_factorNew <- df_factor
for (i in 1:length(col)){
  if (is.na(df_factor[j,i]) == T){
  df_factorNew[j,i] <- as.numeric(nlevels(df_factor[,i])) #I am stuck here
}
```

should do the job

Answer (score 0):

Borrowing Ronak's data:

Using `dplyr::recode_factor` and its `missing` argument:

```
library(dplyr)
df %>% mutate_if(is.factor, recode_factor, missing ="some_value")

#         col1 col2       col3
# 1 some_value    1 some_value
# 2          a    2          n
# 3          b    3          o
# 4          c    4          p
# 5          d    5          q
# 6          e   NA some_value
```

with base R:

```
fct_lgl <- sapply(df,is.factor)
df[fct_lgl] <- lapply(
  df[fct_lgl], 
  function(x) {
    x <- addNA(x)
    levels(x)[nlevels(x)] <- "some_value"
    x})

df
#         col1 col2       col3
# 1 some_value    1 some_value
# 2          a    2          n
# 3          b    3          o
# 4          c    4          p
# 5          d    5          q
# 6          e   NA some_value
```